# Get unique values for a certain category

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, formulas

I am trying to get unique values for a certain category:

[image]

Here you can find the example spreadsheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13RNL6FiJNwZHb78Rkgksx3-JmkW9CGtc7N0WFK2X9A0/edit?usp=sharing

Where I am hanging is, how to get the values for a certain category. Then I can get the `unique function` and display all unique values.

Any suggestions?

I appreciate your replies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:
In D1 enter:

```
=unique(query(A1:B13,"select B where A= 'Category 1' label B 'Category 1'" ))
```

In E1 enter:

```
=unique(query(A1:B13,"select B where A= 'Category 2' label B 'Category 2'" ))
```

In F1 enter:

```
=unique(query(A1:B13,"select B where A= 'Category 3' label B 'Category 3'" ))
```

If you don't mind all data in one column, you can try:

```
={unique(query(A1:B13,"select B where A= 'Category 1' label B 'Category 1'" ));unique(query(A1:B13,"select B where A= 'Category 2' label B 'Category 2'" ));unique(query(A1:B13,"select B where A= 'Category 3' label B 'Category 3'" ))}
```

If you category list is going to expand, you could change the range ro A1:B and add 'and A is not null to the queries like:

```
=unique(query(A1:B,"select B where A= 'Category 1' and A is not null label B 'Category 1'" ))
```